# Reading a Light Dimmer from a Netduino

Tags: dimmer, netduino

I know there are lots of questions and instructions on how to use a netduino (a variation of the arduino) as a dimmer.
But all I would like to do is read the output of a light dimmer with my netduino.

Big Picture Idea:

I have my netduino configured with some RGBW strip lights and it works great, but I would like to be able to dim them from a standard wall light dimmer like this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Lutron-S-600P-WH-600-Watt-Skylark-Single-Pole/dp/B000MAVU2A/ref=sr_1_19?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1456953055&sr=1-19&keywords=light+dimmer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MAVU2A)

The thing is, I have no idea how a dimmer works.  Is it a potentiometer?  Something else?  Is there a particular one I should buy that would easily work?

I would like it to be thin, because I would like it to stay on the wall with adhesives, as I live in an apartment so I can't go knocking holes in the wall to add another light switch.

Comment: (1) This [application note (ST AN2263)](http://www.jameco.com/jameco/products/prodds/811760.pdf) will give you an idea about inner workings of a typical AC dimmer.  (2) Do you need to use a dimmer, or you only want a slider that dimmer presents?

Comment: I just want to be able to read the position of the slider with the netduino.  I don't care about the actual dimming functions

Answer (score 1):

A dimmer is a potentiometer with some eletronic components around to handle mains voltages. Remove all the electronics and keep the potentiometer for your application. Simple as that.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but how do I read a potentiometer with my netduino?

Comment: I'm not familiar with netduino, but if it has an A/D converter you can use it to measure the potentiometer position like this reference: https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/potentiometer

Answer (score 0):

Dimmer like this is used for high voltage, I think that for your project you can just simple potentiometer. 
The simplest dimmers are built on the semiconductor switching elements. Triacs, thyristors, and high-voltage transistors

Comment: I guess I mainly like the dimmer because of the aesthetics for the apartment.  Is there any way just to read from the slider itself?

Comment: Just an idea, maybe somebody will help you further: it may be possible to read the light output with a phototransistor and from that (either by analog integration or by some digital calculation) reconstruct the position of the slider. This approach has the advantage of keeping you away from dangerous voltages.

Comment: The slider is a potentiometer - its mechanically different, but 'electronically' its exactly the same as the rotary ones. So you can take your favorite slider dimmer and strip out everything except the slider potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the dimmer switch as you'll be dumping most of it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffF864.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Reading a potentiometer.*

- Using a potentiometer you can vary the 'potential' or voltage on the wiper by sliding it from one end to the other. In your case one end would be connected to GND and the other to +3.3 V.
- The wiper is connected to an analog input and the code reads that as a digital value between 0 and 1024.
- Potentiometers come in linear or rotary forms. If you don't have equipment to cut a slot for a linear potentiometer then go for a rotary as it only requires a circular hole.

There's an article on [CodeBlack.nl](http://blog.codeblack.nl/post/NetDuino-Getting-Started-with-ADC.aspx) which looks like it may be what your require.

An alternative is to use an up and down button on digital inputs to increase and decrease the light intensity.